# Cannot edit sharepoint on PC after Windows update

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am an owner at my SharePoint 2010 Standard Intranet Server and recently updated my PC with Windows 10 Anniversary. I noticed that now when I try to click on Edit Page, I get the following error:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurs while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 400

When trying to edit an announcement, I get the following message:

The webpage cannot be found: This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.

This happens on all browsers on my PC.

If I connect to another PC, it works just fine, so there is no problem on the server. I can't do a System Restore, because the restore point before the update isn't available any more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening it with the Microsoft Edge browser?  If so, try going to Open in Internet Explorer in the menu and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Same error on all browsers.